# linq sql where closest to number

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

i have a table

```
Id Number
1   9
2   10
3   12
4   19
5   20
```

select Id where Number is closest to 18
it should return row 4 which is 19

how do i write this in linq and tsql? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(from q in table
 orderby Math.Abs(18 - q.Number)
 select q).FirstOrDefault()
```

and

```
SELECT TOP 1
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    ABS(10 - Number)
```

and for a datetime

```
var nearTo = new DateTime(1999, 12, 31);
(from q in table
 orderby Math.Abs((nearTo - q.Date).TotalSeconds)
 select q).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Oops - I think you mean Math.Abs(18 - q.Number). +1 though.

Comment: what if it's a datetime type?

Comment: It will work, except you have to get the TotalSeconds or similar from the timespan returned.

Comment: Oh, keep in mind that "TotalSeconds" may not be the best actual measure for two reasons: It may not be granular enough, and, you may get arithmetic overflows.